# Could not extract native JNI library [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, gradle, dart

I'm having this problem when I tried  to run my code for the first time in android studio using dart (flutter)

this happens : 
[image: click for the image]

Answer (score -1):

The main reason is that your path has some special characters(like !) in it.

1. You can create another user account in windows and copy the old data in it.
2. Or you can try using Ubuntu.